# Update OpenSSL on CentOS 6.5

Tags: openssl, centos

I have 2 CentOS servers. On one server I have OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013 and on the other one I have OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008.
How can I update OpenSSL 0.9.8 to 1.0.1 or newer?
I tried yum update, yum update openssl but I receive No Packages marked for Update.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CentOS 5 does not have an official package of openssl newer than 0.9.8 so you cannot upgrade the system package to 1.0.1.

If you need 1.0.1 on the CentOS 5 server you can compile/package it yourself but you **cannot** replace the 0.9.8 package/files without recompiling everything else on the system as well.

Answer (score 6):

This will do the trick, working great for Centos/Redhad servers:

1. Visit [openssl.org](https://www.openssl.org/source/) for the latest version.
2. Replace **openssl-1.0.2** with the latest version (found on [openssl.org](https://www.openssl.org/source/)) in the commands below
3. Open PuTTY and login as root using your serverIP and SSH port number
   [image: PuTTY]
4. Follow the steps below

> 1. $ cd /usr/src
> 2. $ wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2.tar.gz -O openssl-1.0.2.tar.gz
> 3. $ tar -zxf openssl-1.0.2.tar.gz
> 4. $ cd openssl-1.0.2
> 5. $ ./config
> 6. $ make
> 7. $ make test
> 8. $ make install
> 9. $ openssl version

---

Step 5: The following steps are only needed if old version is still displayed, this will help if it's still is showing the old version:

> 10. $ mv /usr/bin/openssl /root/
> 11. $ ln -s /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
> 12. openssl version

You can use `exit` to exit PuTTY

Comment: This will do it for one server.  If I have to update a server farm to the latest openssl version, creating your own rpm with the 1.0.2j source is the best way to go..!

Comment: @ronak Yes, that's true, it's better to create your own rpm if you need to update a lot of servers, complex server network or if this is what you do every day. If you choose to write your own rpm to this task, you should test it well before using the custom written rpm on production server(s)

Comment: -1. ***DO NOT DO THIS***  You can break your system.  [OpenSSL 1.1.0 and later is not binary-compatible](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_1.1.0_Changes) with the 1.0.2-based version in Centos 7 or the 0.9.8-based version in Centos 6.  `ln -s /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl` will also get overwritten by any updated `openssl` executable from any subsequent update to the OS package.  And do you plan on recompiling and reinstalling every time a security update to OpenSSL is needed?